# How to delete curly brackets from tkinter label

Tags: python, tkinter, format

Pretty straightforward question, just wondering if there's any .format() way to remove squiggly brackets.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

my_list = ['Air Conditioning']

Label_1 = Label(root, text=my_list)
Label_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Current output is: {Air Conditioning}

Trying to get: Air Conditioning

Comment: In your own words, why do you use a list instead of just a string for the `text` value?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It probably wasn't the best example, I used a list in my code with multiple elements

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the list, instead try passing the first element in the list, like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

my_list = ['Air Conditioning']

Label_1 = Label(root, text=my_list[0])
Label_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively, remove the square brackets and just pass a string:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

my_string = 'Air Conditioning'

Label_1 = Label(root, text=my_string)
Label_1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If my list had 5 elements, is there any way of printing all of them at once without curly brackets?

Comment: You could join the list together in to one big string, like " ".join(my_list), the " " adds a space between each element in the list.

Comment: Either that or create separate labels for each string.